# md (markdown) pages giving 404

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I've recently started using GitHub pages and I'm facing the following issue. As you can see in my [repository](https://github.com/s-bhatt/s-bhatt.github.io), I have a `_posts` to store my blog markdowns. I have used the naming convention of `YYYY-MM-DD-title-of-my-post.md`.
Now, as you can see with `2017-12-25-shivang-bhatt-site-launched.md`, the content inside is as follows:

```
---
layout: post
title: "Shivang Bhatt, Launches Site"
date: 2017-12-25
---

Well...some text.
```

Now for the layout part of this, my `_layouts` contains a `post.html` with the following content:

```
---
layout: default
---
<h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
<p class="meta">{{ page.date | date_to_string }}</p>

<div class="post">
  {{ content }}
</div>
```

The issue I am facing is this. The URL which should host this post page, http://s-bhatt.github.io/2017/12/25/shivang-bhatt-site-launched, is giving a 404 - File not found.

I would be extremely grateful for any help or pointers regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `_config.yml` you have set the permalink:

```
permalink: /post/:year/:month/:day/:title
```

so following the filename convention for posts, `2017-12-25-shivang-bhatt-site-launched.md` will be at http://s-bhatt.github.io/post/2017/12/25/shivang-bhatt-site-launched, that is, inside the **post** folder.

If you want to make it work with the url you tried, just remove **post** from `permalink` like:

```
permalink: /:year/:month/:day/:title
```

Answer (score 0):

The right address is

http://s-bhatt.github.io/post/2017/12/25/shivang-bhatt-site-launched

Note `/post` in the middle of it.